# how can get the unicode version in my python3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

The latest unicode version is Unicode 7, according to http://www.unicode.org/versions/.

Which Unicode version was python3.4 built on? How to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`unicodedata` module documentation for Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unicodedata.html):

> The data contained in this database is compiled from the UCD version 6.3.0.

The [`unicodedata.unidata_version` value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.unidata_version) tells you the version used your current Python installation; demo on Python 3.4:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.unidata_version
'6.3.0'
```

Python 3.5 (first alpha [due out in February 2015](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478/)) will use Unicode 7.0.0.

Comment: [Vulcan salute can be expressed as one character (U+1F596) now](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-7.0/U70-1F300.pdf).